# How to change the control themes in a Win32 API application?

Tags: c++, c, api, winapi, visual-styles

If I create a button in the Win32 API, the default conrol theme looks like a Windows 95/98 button. I remember in the past the Microsoft forums told me how to get the XP style, but I don't recall how to do this. Is there a way to programatically or manually change the control themes in a Win32 application?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to [Enable Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175(VS.85).aspx) by adding a manifest dependency to the common control 6 assembly to your applications manifest.

If you use DevStudio it should be as simple as adding the #pragma directive from the linked page:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32'        
                name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls'
                version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*'
                publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

[SetWindowTheme Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28VS.85%29.aspx) would appear to be the solution. HTH

Comment: I compiled successfully using the following: SetWindowTheme(hButton, L"Explorer", NULL); But I don't see any theme changes. I'm using Vista/VS2003 but I'm assuming that's fine.