# Win32 Dialog Box Button Style not windows 7 themed

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I've created a modal dialog box, like this

```
IDD_FORMVIEW DIALOGEX 500, 200, 257, 98
STYLE DS_ABSALIGN | DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU

FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "xxx",IDC_STATIC,31,32,194,16
    PUSHBUTTON      "OK",IDOK,92,65,76,26
END
```

Is there any way to make the button Windows 7 themed? Meaning with the mouseover highlight and not as dull as it is now, cause it's by default on .NET applications but I can't get it like that here.

Comment: have you embedded any manifests allowing to use XP+ theming options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the control themes in a Win32 API application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524009/how-to-change-the-control-themes-in-a-win32-api-application)

Comment: With questions like this, it would also be relevant to include a tag describing your development environment (visual studio / mingw etc) as the solutions can differ depending on the build environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clear duplicate of existing questions. The canonical answer by Microsoft is the MSDN article on [Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Basically, your application needs to have an application manifest file that lists the Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls 6.0.0.0 assembly as a dependentAssembly.